# Matplotlib Deprecation Warning : The is_first_col function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4 and will be removed two minor releases later

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I run the below code to make subplots with this data set

```
data1=pd_read(file.csv)


       p               cv       V     dV     Dp         Radius      DVr       lnr     Dvlnr
0   1.062790    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.062790    100.396127  0.000000    4.609124    0.000000
1   1.081085    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.018295    98.697142   0.000000    4.592056    0.000000
2   1.104370    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.023285    96.616170   0.000000    4.570746    0.000000
3   1.126823    0.000300    0.000185    0.000185    0.022453    94.691003   0.000098    4.550619    0.009212
4   1.150108    0.000599    0.000370    0.000185    0.023285    92.773896   0.000098    4.530165    0.009035
5   1.179214    0.000599    0.000370    0.000000    0.029106    90.484000   0.000000    4.505173    0.000000
6   1.204994    0.000599    0.000370    0.000000    0.025780    88.548159   0.000000    4.483547    0.000000
7   1.224121    0.000898    0.000555    0.000185    0.019127    87.164586   0.000136    4.467798    0.011734
8   1.258217    0.000898    0.000555    0.000000    0.034096    84.802542   0.000000    4.440326    0.000000
9   1.283165    0.000898    0.000555    0.000000    0.024948    83.153764   0.000000    4.420691    0.000000
10  1.335556    0.001198    0.000740    0.000185    0.052391    79.891820   0.000059    4.380673    0.004633
11  1.377136    0.001198    0.000740    0.000000    0.041580    77.479639   0.000000    4.350015    0.000000
12  1.407074    0.001497    0.000925    0.000185    0.029938    75.831122   0.000115    4.328509    0.008593
13  1.477760    0.001797    0.001111    0.000185    0.070686    72.203876   0.000054    4.279494    0.003783
14  1.524330    0.001797    0.001111    0.000000    0.046570    69.997966   0.000000    4.248466    0.000000
15  1.552605    0.002096    0.001295    0.000185    0.028275    68.723210   0.000148    4.230087    0.010055
16  1.634102    0.002096    0.001295    0.000000    0.081497    65.295802   0.000000    4.178928    0.000000
17  1.721420    0.002096    0.001295    0.000000    0.087318    61.983711   0.000000    4.126872    0.000000
18  1.767990    0.002096    0.001295    0.000000    0.046570    60.351020   0.000000    4.100178    0.000000
19  1.805412    0.002396    0.001481    0.000185    0.037422    59.100084   0.000151    4.079232    0.008852

fig, axes=plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 10))
data1.plot(ax=axes[0,0], x='Radius', y='V',color='y', logx=True)
data1.plot(ax=axes[0,1], x='Radius', y='DVr', logx=True)

data1.plot(ax=axes[1,0], x='Radius', y='dvdp', color='y', logx=True)

data1.plot(ax=axes[1,1], x='Radius', y='Dvlnr', logx=True)
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.savefig("out.png")

plt.show(block=False)
```

I get the following error.

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The is_first_col function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use ax.get_subplotspec().is_first_col() instead.
  if ax.is_first_col():
```

I read few articles and did all the suggestions like `plt.show(block=False)` still the problem persists.
Here is a snapshot of [Error Message and code which I am running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7mGO.png)

Comment: What is the object data1?

Comment: @Jody Klymak, data1 is my data frame, data1=pd.read_csv('final.csv')
type(data1):pandas.core.frame.DataFrame; whereas Radius, V and DVr are columns in my data.

Comment: @JohanC, Thanks, is there any way to sort it out? Because it doesn't look nice when working on Jupiter notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning means that your installed version of pandas is using deprecated functionality in matplotlib. This was fixed [in this pull request](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/40718) which was merged early April.

The first pandas release that includes this fix was [1.2.4](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.4.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Could you please suggest how to install Pandas from the master branch on GitHub? I am using PyCharm as IDE.

Comment: @akshahi17 you can follow the documentation at [Installing from source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html#installing-from-source). But be aware that the master branch might have new bugs that haven't been found yet, so if something seems to break be suspicious.

Comment: It might be simpler to disable these kinds of warnings for your session. There's a lot of content about that too on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me, You just need to upgrade pandas, using this code:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: thanks. Your suggestion worked for me. I no longer get the warning about deprecation