# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_first_col'

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Consider this minimal code example for Python/Jupyter using `pandas` (1.5.3) and and `matplotlib.pyplot` (3.7.1). `numpy` is not relevant, as it's only used to generate random data.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Random data
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 1)), columns=list('v'))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 1)), columns=list('v'))

# Create a basic figure
fig = plt.figure()

# Add first axis
ax_1 = fig.add_axes([
    0.0, # left
    0.0, # bottom
    0.5, # width
    1.0  # height
])
df_1.plot(ax=ax_1)

# Add second axis
ax_2 = fig.add_axes([0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
df_2.plot(ax=ax_2)
```

What I want to achieve is to successfully create two axes on a figure. I am aware that I could use `fig.add_subplot()` as well but for exact positioning I do not want to rely on any adjustments by matplolib's layouting.

Instead I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 23
     21 # Add second axis
     22 ax_2 = fig.add_axes([0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
---> 23 df_2.plot(legend=False, ax=ax_2)

File ~/dev/bdstb/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py:1000, in PlotAccessor.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    997             label_name = label_kw or data.columns
    998             data.columns = label_name
-> 1000 return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)

File ~/dev/bdstb/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py:71, in plot(data, kind, **kwargs)
     69         kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
     70 plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
---> 71 plot_obj.generate()
     72 plot_obj.draw()
     73 return plot_obj.result

File ~/dev/bdstb/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:455, in MPLPlot.generate(self)
    453 self._add_table()
    454 self._make_legend()
--> 455 self._adorn_subplots()
    457 for ax in self.axes:
    458     self._post_plot_logic_common(ax, self.data)
...
--> 400     is_first_col = lambda x: x.get_subplotspec().is_first_col()
    401 else:
    402     is_first_col = lambda x: x.is_first_col()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_first_col'
```

I am aware of this `pandas` [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11520) but the solution with adding `colorbar=False` doesn't work in this case.

What is the culprit here?

Comment: `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0})` `df_1.plot(ax=ax1)` `df_2.plot(ax=ax2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your code, you have to downgrade your version of `matplotlib<3.7` (and open a [bug to GH](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Bug%2CNeeds%20Triage&projects=&template=bug_report.yaml&title=BUG%3A%20)):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(mpl.__version__)
# Output: 3.6.3

# your code here

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can check this QA: [Matplotlib Deprecation Warning : The is_first_col function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4 and will be removed two minor releases later](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67778514/15239951)

Comment: FYI https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53553

Comment: Thanks. I hope the team will fix it soon!

Comment: This has been fixed for good in Pandas 2.0.3

Comment: @BastiTee. This is a good news! Thanks